# key expired in android push notification

Tags: android, push, google-cloud-messaging

after following numbers tutorial on how to create push notifications, yesterday I created the apk with eclipse, I installed it on my device and notifications worked. Both the server and the client. This morning tried again and it gives me the error: "key expired"! I have uninstalled and reinstalled the app and it immediately worked. The app must establish a system to counteract this. Help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We shouldn't do Register and Un-register every time you start or stop the application. You should use un-register in a rare situations.

[Please read the link for more information.](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#unreg-why)

[Read this to know about sync in registration ID](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#reg-state)

Comment: Almost certainly I'm making is that a register unregister, and then it is obvious that the key has expired. but how do I fix this situation?

Comment: As far as i know there will be a call from Google server to client app intimating the expiry of the registration. We need to re-register and update the new id to third party server. I will get back to you with the proper link for that.

Comment: However, you will use GCM.jar for th eimplementation and it will contain onRegistration method. Just update your third party server in this method.